# SQL Server : CASE statement varbinary comparison has unexpected behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, comparison-operators, varbinary, case-statement

UPDATE:
It appears there may be some certificate or rule running on open queries with enrypted column data. I have discovered that the following produces an unencrypted value concat 'more'. I will have to verify with our DBA what may cause this behavior.

```
case when s.EncryptedColumn is not null then concat(s.[EncryptedColumn], ' more') else s.[RawColumn] end
```

I am trying to do a simple comparison to null against a `varbinary(16)` column however I cannot get the result to return true.

This is what I have tried:

Attempt 1:

```
select 
    s.[EncryptedColumn], 
    (case when s.[EncryptedColumn] is not null 
            then s.[EncryptedColumn] 
            else s.[RawColumn] 
     end) as 'result'
```

Result 1: encrypted data, raw data

Attempt 2:

```
select 
    datalength(s.[EncryptedColumn]), 
    (case when datalength(s.[EncryptedColumn]) > 0 
            then s.[EncryptedColumn] 
            else s.[RawColumn] 
     end) as 'result'
```

Result 2: encrypted data length (16), raw data

Any ideas?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Where are these results? I don't see how the text after result1 is correlated with the query in attempt 1?

Comment: Does `coalesce(EncryptedColumn, RawColumn)` do what you need? `datalength(null)` is null, by the way. So that's probably one problem with the second attempt.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @MartinSmith.

I have a non-null encrypted column and both selects return evidence that it is not null in the first column selected. Only the result of the case is always false.

Comment: @marc_s, thank you for the formatting edit. I am using SQL Server 2014

Comment: It might be helpful to get a sense of the values you're dealing with. The first attempt suggests you really want a `coalesce()`. The second suggests maybe you're doing `datalength(0x)`. Is there more to the story? I don't want to see the data you've got encrypted of course.

Comment: @shawnt00, 
(1) encrypted column data is 0x343030303034313131 with a datalength of 9
(2) coalesce(EncryptedColumn, RawColumn) produced the the raw column data.

Comment: Is it possible that you've got a union or some other kind of thing going on in the full query that inadvertently transposed the columns and/or gave them aliases that you weren't expecting? Everything looks good to me unless SQL Server 2014 added some weird null settings that I don't know about yet.

Comment: Interestingly, casting as an int results in 'yes'.  
_case when cast(s.EncryptedColumn as int) > 0 then 'yes' else 'no' end_  

But does not return the encrypted column data when attempting:  
_case when cast(s.EncryptedColumn as int) > 0 then s.[EncryptedColumn] else s.[RawColumn] end_

Comment: please forgive my formatting

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you should take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775443/strategies-for-checking-isnull-on-varbinary-fields):

> use ISNULL(DATALENGTH(Content), -1) instead, so that you can
>   distinguish between length 0 and NULL. Or just use DATALENGTH(Content)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
It appears there may be some certificate or rule running on open queries with enrypted column data. I have discovered that the following produces an unencrypted value concat 'more'. I will have to verify with our DBA what may cause this behavior.

```
case when s.EncryptedColumn is not null then concat(s.[EncryptedColumn], ' more') else s.[RawColumn] end
```